# material-ui.dropzone: You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: reactjs, webpack, material-ui, babeljs

Integrating material-ui-dropzone in my React app, I got this error:

> ./~/material-ui-dropzone/src/index.jsx Module parse failed:
>   ...\client\node_modules\material-ui-dropzone\src\index.jsx Unexpected
>   token (123:26) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file
>   type. SyntaxError: Unexpected token (123:26)

Here is my webpack configuration:

```
const Path = require('path'); const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin'); const Webpack = require('webpack'); const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = (options) => {   const ExtractSASS = new ExtractTextPlugin(`/styles/${options.cssFileName}`);

  const webpackConfig = {
    devtool: options.devtool,
    entry: [
      `webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:${+ options.port}`,
      'webpack/hot/dev-server',
      Path.join(__dirname, '../src/app/index'),
    ],
    output: {
      path: Path.join(__dirname, '../dist'),
      filename: `/scripts/${options.jsFileName}`,
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
    },
    module: {
      loaders: [{
        test: /.jsx?$/,
        include: Path.join(__dirname, '../src/app'),
        loader: 'babel',
      }],
    },
    plugins: [
      new Webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
          NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(options.isProduction ? 'production' : 'development'),
        },
        "global.GENTLY": false
      }),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: Path.join(__dirname, '../src/index.html'),
      }),
    ],
    node: {
      __dirname: true,
    },

  };

  if (options.isProduction) {
    webpackConfig.entry = [Path.join(__dirname, '../src/app/index')];

    webpackConfig.plugins.push(
      new Webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
      new Webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        compressor: {
          warnings: false,
        },
      }),
      ExtractSASS
    );

    webpackConfig.module.loaders.push({
      test: /\.scss$/,
      loader: ExtractSASS.extract(['css', 'sass']),
    });   } else {
    webpackConfig.plugins.push(
      new Webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    );

    webpackConfig.module.loaders.push({
      test: /\.scss$/,
      loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass'],
    });

    webpackConfig.devServer = {
      contentBase: Path.join(__dirname, '../'),
      hot: true,
      port: options.port,
      inline: true,
      progress: true,
      historyApiFallback: true,
      stats: 'errors-only',
    };   }

  return webpackConfig; 

};
```

Babel config file is:

```
{
  "presets": ["react", "es2015", "stage-1"]
}
```

It is the only library I had problems with. Any idea where might be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using webapck@3.x
Try to modify your babel loader to

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      include: Path.join(__dirname, '../src/app'),
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ["react", "es2015", "stage-1"],
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

You can reference here https://webpack.js.org/loaders/babel-loader/

Noted that in your loader config, write `babel-loader` instead of just `babel`. Also make sure if you have `npm install` the right babel npm packages to the devDependencies, which depends on your webpack version.

If it does not solve your problem, paste your package.json file so i can get to know your webpack version.

Cheers.